# WPF How to center window if it is getting maximimum size?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I have the `Window` with these properties

```
Width="800"
Height="600"
MaxWidth="1000"
MaxHeight="700"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
```

It is located in center of screen when window is opened as suggested. But if I click `Maximize` button (top right corner of window), window become 1000*700 (it's OK) and moves to top left corner of screen (It's a problem).

Is it possible to hold window in center of screen if it change its size?

Comment: I guess Maximize will maximize the screen and that has no alignment.  I think you are asking for Restore.

Comment: ehm... what? I mean you maximize the window to fill your whole screen? How could it be at the center then?

Comment: Do you mean that controls of the window stay at the Top Left corner, while window size become bigger?

Comment: hide windows maximize option and instead write your own which asks windows for screen size then just take those values to be your windows height and width. I remeber using WorkingArea.Height or something like that ages ago...

Answer (score 0):

What your is want is not possible in simple ways, because when we `maximize` the `window`, it renders `window` from top-left corner of the screen. And if you try to move the `window`, it restores the `window`. Even you cannot reset the `location` of a `window` if it is in `maximize` state.

For your solution, you will have to hide the border of the `window` and will have to implement the `titlebar` with all buttons(minimize, maximize and close) on your own. Then you can provide this feature